# How to have a subscript with \sigma?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I had tried using

```
$\sigma$_{AB}
```

and

```
 ($\sigma$_{KL}}\)
```

and

```
\($\sigma$_{KL}}\)
```

and it give a lots of error
[image: mb]

Comment: Yet you haven't tried `$\sigma_{AB}$`...?

Comment: \(\sigma_{AB}\) seemed work. But not sure what is the different

Comment: What environment are you using? Overleaf? Something else? Neither of the 3 code snippets you listed in your post would yield what you're after; that is, it would produce an error.

Comment: @Werner, yes, overleaf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the suggested code snippets will work:

- `$\sigma$_{AB}`

  This has the subscript `_` outside of math mode. Subscripts via `_` only work in math mode.
- `($\sigma$_{KL}}\)`

  This is similar to the first attempt, except there's a closing brace `}` with no accompanying opening brace `{` - this will lead to an error. Additionally, the closing math mode `\)` has no accompanying opening `\(`.
- `\($\sigma$_{KL}}\)`

  Similar to the above, except that you cannot enter math mode `$`...`$` within math mode `\(`...`\)` (or the other way around).

You need

```
$\sigma_{KL}$
```

or

```
\(\sigma_{KL}\)
```

Overleaf may continue automatic compilation if the error is resolvable. In certain instances, this may seem like code is working, when actually there is an error. It such cases, its often better to view the code log from the compilation and see what (and where) the error occurred.